# Android ChipGroup IllegalArgumentException, even though using MaterialComponents theme

Tags: android, material-components-android

I'm using a `com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup` in an AppCompatActivity, but when I try to make a Chip, I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).`. I have tried every possible Theme.MaterialComponents theme (yes, even .Bridge), and I'm still getting the error. Somewhere else in the app, I'm also using a chipgroup and making new chips, and everything works fine. What am I missing here?

Relevant in MyActivity:

```
Chip chip = new Chip(getApplicationContext());
```

Relevant in MyActivity xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:id="@+id/filter_chips"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.appname">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppName">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"/>
        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Style:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.AppName" 
        parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">? 
        attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use application context, use the activity's context. Application context does not have material theme enabled in it.

Comment: Ok, I forgot that getting the context in AppCompatActivity is as simple as writing "this". Thanks for the help.